# Working with dataframes from unique function

Tags: r

I was wondering how I could go about changing some data like this from a dataframe i created:

```
Variable Freq                           and       Variable Freq                
01       3                                        M        10
02       2                                        
03       4
04       5
```

to

```
01       3                                        
02       2                                        
03       4
04       5
M        10
```

The code i am using to get those 2 tables is :

```
y = as.data.frame(length(unique(index_visit$PatientID)))
x = as.data.frame(table(index_visit$ProcedureID))
```

Comment: Try `rbind(DF1,DF2)`. Your `x` and `y` are rather strange data.frames, by the way. For example, `y` should have only one value in it, according to your code `as.data.frame(length(...anything...))`

Comment: yeah sorry about that.  that was just some sample output.  I tried to use R bind but it gave me the error:   

Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : numbers of columns of arguments do not match

Comment: Np. Check out `names(x)` and `names(y)` to see that they do not have the same number of columns, as the error says.

Comment: ah i see, there is only one column from the length.  is there any way to make it 2 columns so like: PatientIDs, freq?

Comment: Not sure. You'd have to provide a reproducible example. I suspect that reading the documentation for the functions producing `x` and `y`, by typing `?table` etc., would be more helpful than posting such a question, though. Reference on question-asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @ChristopherYee. Yes you can with the `aggregate` function like so: `aggregate(list(freq=index_visit$PatientID),by=list(PatientIDs = index_visit$PatientID),FUN=length)`